# Slow performance with jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, jquery-selectors

I'm rendering over 600 forms in an MVC format (php Codeigniter). Each one of these forms has a button labeled "More Options". When you click this button -  a hidden div, located in the same parent element, is toggled, displaying more input fields and data. The problem is that the sibling toggle is quick in console, but when I click the actual button, it takes very long to trigger.

Using id's is the recommended fix, but it is slightly impractical when I have this many div elements to go through.

Here is my js file

```
jQuery(document.ready(function(){
    jQuery("form >button[name='more_data'].meta_button").click( function(){  
        jQuery(this).siblings("div.meta").toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Here is the structure (there are 650 of these div's, with more to come)

```
<div>
    <li id="bCIya8DZyr4idseJe5cbLA" class="even">
        <form action="url" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <div class="space_name"></div>
            <button name="more_data" type="button" class="meta_button">More Options</button>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
            <div class="meta" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;">
                <div class="meta_block">Set Estimates:
                    <div class="input_estimate">1:
                        <input type="number" name="estimate_1" value="" id="estimate_1" class="estimate">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_estimate">2:
                        <input type="number" name="estimate_2" value="" id="estimate_2" class="estimate">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_estimate">3:
                        <input type="number" name="estimate_3" value="" id="estimate_3" class="estimate">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </li>
</div>
```

Note: I'm running jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: You could try using `.nextAll()` instead of `.siblings()`. Why do you have so many forms?

Comment: If applicable, change "div.meta" to ".meta".

Comment: What code are you using in the console that is fast?

Comment: `[name='more_data'].meta_button` seems redundant?!

Comment: The siblings selector seems also very fast: http://jsperf.com/jquery-siblings-vs-parent-find-vs-find

Comment: @powtac would that slow performance?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a rendering problem ? Like a complex reflow and costly CSS rules ? The code we see looks pretty fast in my experience.

Comment: @lonesomeday I gave the button an id, and when run with the above code, it ran at the desirable speed

Comment: as far as I can see, .meta_button is an additional not required selector. Therefor form >button[name='more_data'] is already enough.

Comment: attribute selectors are slow; if you don't really need it I would remove it and just select by class.

Comment: @Fuhton Again, the actual code you used would be helpful. As would a minimal working example, if you can set one up...

Comment: get rid of > if possible, that thing is really slow

Comment: As-is, your markup is invalid, an li element can't be the direct child of a div. That shouldn't affect performance though.

Comment: @KevinB There is a <ul> above the div. Thought that could go implied.

Comment: @Fuhton that's still invalid code

Comment: maybe it might be a better idea to defer the toggle until user scrolls to that part of the page, this will speed up performance by a lot since you won't be doing 50 of these at once

Comment: @Huangism I like the idea of loading the toggle based on page location and is something definitely worth a try.

Comment: Bind event to scroll to check if the form element is in your view, if it is, do your toggle. This check also needs to happen on page load for the initial view to be corrected by toggle. I would recommend you do the toggling after scroll is done or you might run into performance issues when scrolling

Answer (score 3):

### Don't use a delegate

Using a delegate (`.on()` with a selector) like @jrummell suggested is faster when you have multiple event listeners, because you reduce the number of listeners to one.

### Simpler selector using a class

So in this case though I would recommend using a simpler selector:

```
$(function(){
    $('.meta_button').on('click', function(){
        $(this).siblings('div.meta').toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

This way you have quite simpler selector and less checks when a click is triggered, because there is no delegate. Also the clicks on other elements in the forms are not captured.

### Animations slow things  down

An animation could slow things down. An animation which is performed over multiple elements simultaneously even more.

Try moving all `div.meta` elements in a single parent and applying animation only on that single element.

You could also remove the animation entirely by just using `toggle()` (the comment about the multiple items is still valid in this case).

**Example**:

```
$(function(){
    $('.meta_button').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.meta_holder').toggle();
        // OR
        // $(this).next('.meta_holder').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: This did speed up the rendering slightly. Milliseconds shaved off.

Comment: @Fuhton Rendering is an entirely different world. You asked about the speed of the jQuery selectors and stuff.

Comment: what browser are you using? rendering stuff could be slow in particular browsers and fast in others

Comment: if there is an ID which contains all of the meta buttons, you should add that to the selector as well

Comment: Was using Chrome and Chromium.

Comment: $('#containerID').find('button.meta_button').on(...) will be faster then just $('.meta_button').

Answer (score 0):

Including jQuery.ui.css made the redisplay incredibly slow. Costly css rules killed the display and slowed down rendering times. The "nudge in the right direction" is in the comments of the question.

Comment: This solves your problem, but does not answer your question. It should be a comment to the question IMHO.

Comment: The question was why does the jQuery take so long to trigger. The answer was because of costly css rules.